# Get Latitude and Longitude from a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude from the 'coordinates' column in the following dataframe and create the respective 'latitude' and 'longitude' columns in the same df without success.

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Wakefield', 'Co-op City'], 
                   'coordinates': ['[[-73.84720055104846, 40.89470566842616]]', '[[-73.82993909620285, 40.87429474550749]]']})
```

The code:

```
test_df['Lat'] = test_df.coordinates.str.split('[[',1)[1].split(']]')[0].split(', ')[1]
test_df['Lon'] = test_df.coordinates.str.split('[[',1)[1].split(']]')[0].split(', ')[0]

Output: 
error: unterminated character set at position 0
```

However if I do the same on a single string it works.

```
coord = '[[-73.84720055104846, 40.89470566842616]]'
#longitute
longitude = coord.split('[[',1)[1].split(']]')[0].split(', ')[0]
print('Longitude: ',longitude)

Longitude:  -73.84720055104846
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this dataframe you have a string not a list, so you need to use pandas string accessor, `.str` and using [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods).

Use this code:

```
test_df[['Lat', 'Long']] = test_df['coordinates'].str.strip('\[|\]')\
                                                 .str.split(',', expand=True)

test_df
```

Output:

```
         name                                coordinates                 Lat                Long
0   Wakefield  [[-73.84720055104846, 40.89470566842616]]  -73.84720055104846   40.89470566842616
1  Co-op City  [[-73.82993909620285, 40.87429474550749]]  -73.82993909620285   40.87429474550749
```